# Squashed Google Graphs when using wkhtmltopdf

Tags: javascript, graph

For my blog (http://ios-blog.co.uk) I am using wkhtml: https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/ to convert a page with analytics Data on to a pdf. The graph is generated by Google Graphs API. (https://google-developers.appspot.com/chart/interactive/docs/quick_start)

This is the code that is generating the Graph:

```
var options = {
                        series: {
                            0: {targetAxisIndex: 0},
                            1: {targetAxisIndex: 1}
                        },
                        vAxes:{
                            0: {title: 'Impressions', minValue: 0},
                            1: {title: 'Clicks', minValue: 0}
                        }
                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chartContainer'));
                    chart.draw(data, options);
```

On the webpage the image comes out like:

[a busy cat http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/graph/graphLarge.png](http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/graph/graphLarge.png)
![Google Graph Large][1]

However on the Generated PDF the graph comes out like:

[a busy cat http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/graph/graphSmall.png](http://markpetherbridge.co.uk/graph/graphSmall.png)
![Google Graph Small][2]

As you can see, the image is not being squashed, it seems to be missing things out of the 'x' axis and making the graph smaller.

Can anyone shed some light onto this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came across the same issue what I did was compress the width of the body tag in the html document you are trying to convert keeping the char div the same.

The body tag width I set to: 
body { width: 795px !important; }

And kept the chart div and ChartArea in the Javascript to 1200px
chartArea:{width:1200,height:300}

I hope this helps!